# mover la cabeza diciendo que si

Tags: position, three.js

He creado un personaje con formas, cilindro y esfera en el editor Three.js. El cuerpo es un grupo con cilindros y la cabeza es otro grupo con esferas y otros objetos. Lo guardé como GLB y lo cargué correctamente en mi proyecto.

El problema es cuando quiero que la cabeza se mueva diciendo que sí, es decir, quiero que la cabeza gire mirando hacia arriba y luego hacia abajo. El movimiento del no funciona y puedo girar el cuerpo. Pero cuando intento girar la cabeza para simular el si, se sale del cuerpo siguiendo un centro que no he podido cambiar.

[image: personaje cargado]

Lugo cuando muevo el control cabeza x con el comando rotate hace esto

[image: movimientos de si]

La cabeza deveria mirar hacia arriba o hacia abajo

uso este codigo pero no funciona

```
    //calculo punto rotacion cabeza
    const box = new TRES.Box3().setFromObject(cabezaPersonaje);
    const centro = box.getCenter(new TRES.Vector3());
    console.log(centro);
    let centroCabeza = new TRES.Object3D();
    centroCabeza.position.set(centro.x, centro.y, centro.z);
    escena.add(centroCabeza);
```

Agradecería algo de ayuda

Saludos